# How to quantitatively compare parametric density fit and kernel density (KDE) fit of a multivariate data?

Tags: probability, density-estimation

I am working on modeling the joint distribution of given multivariate data. I can fit some parametric distributions on the data and evaluate the fitted models by LogLiklihood and AIC values. However, I am not sure how to evaluate the KDE-based fitting of the data compared to the parametric fit. How can I evaluate the AIC values of the KDE fitting? What would be the number of parameters of KDE fit? I am just using the default bandwidth selection of Matlab for KDE fitting, which, I reckon, selects one bandwidth for all the kernels.

NOTE: I am aware of the two-sample tests like the KS-test and AD-test, or metrics like KL-divergence, Wasserstein distance, and MMD that can do the job of comparison once the samples are drawn from each fit.

Comment: Kernel density approximation is model-free. There is thus no likelihood function, and the AIC is not defined. In some sense, you can consider the KDE estimate as the groundtruth against which the parametric model can be evaluated (this concept is in some contexts called "model calibration").

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this line of thought was what I was intuitionally inclined to, but not very sure. However, I was thinking that as the PDF value at any point can be calculated from the fitted KDE, we can evaluate the likelihood for given data, albeit being model-free.

Comment: Yes, we can compute a likelihood, but this is not a likelihood *function* because it has no argument. Remember that, in the likelihood function, the measured values are fixed and the argument are the parameters of the model.

Comment: That cleared my doubt, thank you.